# Epipolar geometry and fundamental matrix: Is the product equal to the distance from the epipolar lines?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, 3d, computer-vision

Given the [fundamental matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_(computer_vision)) of a stereo camera setup $\boldsymbol{F}$ and two potentially corresponding image points from a left image $(u_l | v_l)$ and a right image $(u_r | v_r)$:
The product
$$
\pmatrix{u_l & v_l & 1} \boldsymbol{F} \pmatrix{u_r \\ v_r \\ 1}
$$
will equal $0$ if the image points meet the [epipolar constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipolar_geometry). Am I right in assuming that if the product doesn't equal $0$ - and therefore the points do not meet the epipolar constraint - it will equal the distance of the points to their corresponding epipolar line in pixels?

Comment: $F$ is uniquely determined only up to a scalar multiple, so I don’t think that you can count on gleaning any metric information from this product.

Comment: @amd My testing tells me the same. I just hoped for my testing to be wrong, because this correlation would’ve made my life a lot easier. Thanks, though. If you want you can make this an answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generally express distance in this manner.

However, if $\mathbf{x}_r$ is a point in homogeneous coordinates and $\mathbf{F}$ a the fundamental matrix, then $$\mathbf{l}_l=\mathbf{F}\mathbf{x}_r$$ is a line in homogeneous coordinates. It can be represented as

$$\mathbf{l}_l=(n_{x},n_{y},-d)^{\top} $$

then you want to scale your vector representation such that

$$1=\sqrt{n_{x}^{2}+n_{y}^{2}}$$

and you will get the actual (signed) distance to the line by multiplication with any point

$$\text{signed distance} = \mathbf{l}_l^\top (u_l,v_l,1)^\top $$

Note the necessary use of the square root. Distance is not a projective quantity.